# Error compile Visual Studio 2019 Project dll with MSBuild 2019, obfuscating with Eazfuscator NET 2018.2 in TeamCity 2020.2.2

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, eazfuscator

I have this error when TeamCity Build Step compile with obfuscating a Visual Studio dll Project with MSBuild:

```
EXEC: error: Error occurred during processing of input file '.dll' -> Cannot load file or assembly 'zx_2cba06c4237a413ea1e8116e71ad61dc, PublicKeyToken = 6205972ab2f0fc68' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the specified file. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (5473,5): error MSB3073: The command "if /I "Release" == "Release" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eazfuscator.NET\Eazfuscator.NET.exe" "E:\Builds\MyDll\bin\Release\MyDll.dll" --msbuild-project-path "E:\Builds\MyDll\MyDll.csproj" --msbuild-project-configuration "Release" --msbuild-project-platform "AnyCPU" --msbuild-solution-path "*Undefined*" -n --newline-flush -v 2018.2" exit with code 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Eazfuscator-.NET-2018.2.2 is not compatible with MSBuild 2019, the solution is use Eazfuscator-.NET-2019.1 as minimun version.